# why i am not getting decimal precision upto 1 digit?

Tags: math, c++14

```
float mean(int a[],int p){
    int sum=0;
    double ans;
    for(int i=0; i<p; ++i){
        sum=sum+a[i];
    }
    ans=sum/p;
    cout<<setprecision(1)<<ans<<endl;
}
```

input: 4897 54012 32015 4684 2122 44848 99999 54651 16161 76482
expected output: 38987.1
my output: 38987.0

Comment: `ans=sum/p;` will do an int/int division, and then convert the result to a double. Use `ans=(double)sum/p;` to first convert the value of sum to a double, then do the division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dividing an int by an int, you get an int. When you set the precision of your answer, you are setting the precision of a number that has already been truncated.

For example, when you have:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 2;
double ans = a / b; //(5/2 = 2)

//ans = 2.0
```

You are working with integer division.

```
a / b
```

is 5 / 2, which yields 2 due to integer division, not 2.5.

Even though you are setting it equal to a double, you still get 2.0, because you are setting ans to the result of 5 / 2, which is 2. The int 2 then is converted to a double: 2.0. To get an answer with the correct decimal approximation, make one of the ints a double (I would suggest changing int p to double p).